# geoman - how to listen to a feature change in edit mode after the feature has been created in draw mode

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-geoman

I am listening to adding a vertex during "draw mode" as documented in docs https://github.com/geoman-io/leaflet-geoman#draw-mode

```js
map.on('pm:drawstart', ({ workingLayer }) => {  
  workingLayer.on('pm:vertexadded', e => {  
    console.log(e);  
  });
});
```

at some point I am done drawing and "draw mode" is ended.

i then want to edit the geometry and enable "edit mode".

how can I listen to edits of the "workingLayer" in which I just draw the geometries?

I tried the following without success...

```js
map.on('pm:drawstart', ({ workingLayer }) => {  
  workingLayer.on('pm:vertexadded', e => {  
    console.log(e);
  });
  workingLayer.on('pm:edit', e => {
    console.log(e);
  });
});
```

update: I then turned on my brain and came up with the following

```js
map.on('pm:globaleditmodetoggled', e => {
  e.map.pm.getGeomanDrawLayers(true).on('pm:edit', e => {
    console.log(e)
  });
});
```

is this the way to do it or does a more efficient way exist'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the listener `pm:create` and add to the new created layer the `pm:edit` listener.
Then the event `pm:edit` will be fired when a edit happens on the new layer.

```
map.on('pm:create', ({ layer}) => {  
  layer.on('pm:edit', e => {
    console.log(e);
  });
});
```